# It is possible to send more than one type of object from JSP to Spring Controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm coding a JSP view that has to send multiple objects to a Spring @Controller once submitted.

The controller's handler has the following signature:

```
public ModelAndView handlerX(@ModelAttribute ModelMap model){
```

I've tried something like this in my JSP:

```
<form method="post" action="action">
<spring:bind path="objectX.name">
    <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" readonly="readonly" />
</spring:bind>
```

But when the debugger reaches the controller, the model object doesn't contain any of the form's values.

Can anybody please give some advice on how to design the form? I think I can not wrap the two different objects in a Command-type-object, as the controller's handler accepts only a ModelMap. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this problem by tailoring your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to bind request paramaters sent from your form to your model argument. For example:

```
public class RequestToModelBindingArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, Ordered {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(final MethodParameter parameter) {
        return  parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(ModelAttribute.class) &&
                parameter.getParameterType() == ModelMap.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(final MethodParameter parameter, final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, final NativeWebRequest webRequest, final WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        ModelMap model = mavContainer.getModel();
        Map<String, String[]> requestParameters = webRequest.getParameterMap();

        // Bind all request parameters to the model
        for (String param : requestParameters.keySet()) {
            String[] values = requestParameters.get(param);
            if (values.length == 1) {
                model.addAttribute(param, values[0]);
            } else {
                model.addAttribute(param, values);
            }
        }

        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

An instance of this class can be added to the argument resolver list your application configuration.

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new RequestToModelBindingArgumentResolver());
}
```

There is a problem though. Arguments annotated with `@ModelAttribute` will be resolved by `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` and since no ordering of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s takes place it will always be the first to resolve the value. This means that if you would add a custom argument resolver it will never be reached. This means that we need to find a way to sort the collection of resolvers *(That is the reason the resolver implements `Ordered`)*.

One easy way to sort the resolver collection is to inject the `RequestmappingHandlerAdapter` into the configuration.

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;
```

Now we need a method to be invoked after the configuration is constructed so we have a chance to sort the collection of resolvers.

```
@PostConstruct
public void orderArgumentResolvers() {
    List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>(adapter.getArgumentResolvers());
    Collections.sort(resolvers, new OrderComparator());
    adapter.setArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
}
```

Since `adapter.getArgumentResolvers()` will return a unmodifiable list we need to jump a little hoop here before the sorting can commence. After sorting, the `RequestToModelBindingArgumentResolver` instance will be on top of the list and the first to respond to the `support()` call.

**But hey! I think it's much easier to just alter the handlers signature :)**

Comment: Woa, great argument resolving lesson :) This is a way to do it. It's hard and ugly, but it solves the question. Thank you very much for your time ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form having fields matching the form fields and then get that form like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
        public Response add(@RequestBody Form form, HttpServletRequest request){
    //The form element's fields must match with fields in your form. Especially the names and types.
    }
```

Apart from these 2 parameters that are passed in add(), you can pass many more

Comment: Thank you very much... I was thinking of something like that, too. The thing is I can't change the controller's parameters, so I must figure out a way to pass two different objects without wrapping them in a sole object >__<

Comment: Why can't you change the handler method? It only accepts a `ModelMap` which has nothing to do with sending form data. It's also strange to have a `@ModelAttribute` on the model itself. Your setup does not make sense.

Comment: Do you think so? The signature of the controller's method was provided by the design team... I guess I'll have to report the problem to them.